# Properties with min and max range looking at other property

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I created an Add-on with lots and lots of min and max values.
How can I made them looking at each other for the min and max value?

```
import bpy 
from bpy.props import FloatProperty

class My_Props(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):


    My_Prop_range_min: FloatProperty(           name="My_Prop_range_min",
                                                default=1,
                                                min=0,
                                                max=100, # <--- This should look at "My_Prop_range_max"
                                                )

    My_Prop_range_max: FloatProperty(           name="My_Prop_range_max",
                                                default=4,
                                                min=0, # <--- This should look at "My_Prop_range_min"
                                                max=100,
                                                )
```

The minimum property should not be able to have a higher value than the maximum property is set, and the maximum property should not be able to have a lower value than the minimum property is set.

Is that possible? How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: The min and max settings are static absolute values. You could however use an update function to check if the `My_Prop_range_min` >= `My_Prop_range_max` and if so force it to be a lower value. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html

Comment: I can't find any example on the Property Definition page. How can I make them update by changing the value in the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example should point you in the right direction:

Any time the `my_prop_range_min` is changed in the UI the update function `upd_min` is called. The function then compares the UI setting to the current value of the `my_prop_range_max`. If the value of `my_prop_range_min` >= `my_prop_range_max` you just force it to be less than the value of `my_prop_range_max`. Similar when comparing max to min.

```
import bpy


def upd_min(self, context):
    if self.my_prop_range_min >= self.my_prop_range_max:
        self.my_prop_range_min = self.my_prop_range_max - 1


def upd_max(self, context):
    if self.my_prop_range_max <= self.my_prop_range_min:
        self.my_prop_range_max = self.my_prop_range_min + 1


class TEST_PG_props(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_prop_range_min: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="My_Prop_range_min",
        default=1,
        min=0,
        max=99,
        update=upd_min,
        )

    my_prop_range_max: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="My_Prop_range_max",
        default=4,
        min=1,
        max=100,
        update=upd_max,
        )


class TEST_PT_test_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "TEST_PT_test_panel"
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test Tab"
 
    def draw(self, context):
        my_props = context.scene.my_props
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(my_props, "my_prop_range_min", text="min")
        row.prop(my_props, "my_prop_range_max", text="max")


classes = [
    TEST_PG_props,
    TEST_PT_test_panel,
    ]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
            type=TEST_PG_props)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_props

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! That way can I figure it out.